# random.randint using the same seed whilst in a loop

Tags: python, distribution, random-seed

I've been having some fun with random numbers, but when trying to generate random numbers whilst in a loop, like in the code below

```
success = 0
times = 0

for i in range(0,10):
    while success == 0:

        numbers = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

        for j in range(0,9):

            x = int(random.randint(0,9))
            numbers[x] = 1

            count = numbers.count(1)

        if count == 1:
            success = 1
        else:
            times += 1


    print(times)
    print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
17160
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17160
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17160
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17160
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17160
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And so forth. I am trying to have a look at the average times it has to try, but getting the same result each time ruins it.
Is there a way to use the `rand` function to get different random numbers each time?

Comment: Are you seeding the random number generator with the same seed every time? That'll give you the same outcome every time. I (as expected) get different results every time using your code.

Comment: How can I change the seed each time then?

Comment: It will be different if you don't specifically set it (it is seeded based on the current time by default). If you're setting it then you'll know that you are because it's a deliberate action, but when getting repetitive "random" numbers it's the first thing to eliminate as a possibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would not know if I was setting it deliberately, but assuming I am not, how does one "Specifically set it" to something, and is it even possible to have a different random number coming out of this, or would I have to add in a small delay for it to work?

Comment: Ah sorry, I've put the wrong code up, correct will be up shortly

Comment: Can you import `time`, call `random.seed(time.clock())` and test it again?

Comment: Once you've set `success = 1`, then `while` doesn't run again and you don't generate new data.

Comment: This is NOT a problem with seeding. The module level random functions are seeded with the current time when the module is loaded. You don't need to do it unless you want a different random source and you do not need to reseed while using random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code repeats until 10 random ints all set the same position in `numbers` . That sets `success` and you try again. The problem is that you never clear `success` so `while success == 0:` is not True and the loop doesn't run. The solution is to reset `success` in the outer loop.

```
success = 0
times = 0

for i in range(0,10):
    while success == 0:

        numbers = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

        for j in range(0,6):

            x = int(random.randint(0,6))
            numbers[x] = 1

            count = numbers.count(1)

        if count == 1:
            success = 1
        else:
            times += 1


    print(times)
    print(numbers)
    success = 0                  # <== the fix
```

Comment: And based on what OP is trying, I think they need to also reset `times`. So best to put both at the top of each iteration attempt (after for, before while).

Comment: @aneroid - Good point. I wasn't sure exactly what the intent of the code is.

Comment: I _think_ they want to count how many times they needed to iterate to get exactly one `1` in the list after potentially trying to do so randomly 6 times in a row. Kinda like saying "how many cycles would it take for one to roll a **7-sided** dice **6 times** and get the same number each time?" Of course, `number` is length 10 but only the **first 7 indexes** are being chosen for the experiment; maybe a reduction just for the SO question (but I don't think so).